# Editing and displaying different "layers" of vertex colors

Tags: vertex-colors

I'm given a mesh with vertex colors that display the original material/color of an object. Now I want to classify these vertex colors according to the different materials they can be divided into.

Here is a dummy-cube for a quick example. The actual color/material:

[image: cube with original material]

The classification into two materials:
[image]

So, I have two different types of vertex color information associated with my object. The mesh I'm given is painted in a more complex way than the cube of course. That's why it would be very useful to see the original vertex colors while painting the vertex colors that encode the material information. Is there any way to achieve this? (like for example how layers are organized in gimp or photoshop) I did not find a satisfying solution so far. Thank's in advance for your help.